# Runtime error when set pivot field by VB.. but only for numeric values

Tags: vba, excel, pivot, pivot-table

I have a field with values both text and numbers. But the data type of the column containing the field is set to text
Example Values in column F1 can be = 100111 , P100T5

My code is:

```
Dim  Value as string

Sheets("Piv").PivotTables("P1").PivotFields("F1").ClearAllFilters
Sheets("Piv").PivotTables("P1").PivotFields("F1").CurrentPage = Value
```

The code works when Value = P100T5 but not when 100111. Basically it doesn't work when it is a number value.

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try ...CurrentPage = CStr(Value).

Comment: still gives me the same error "Application-defined or Object defined error".

Comment: Are you sure the data type of the source column is set to text? Just setting the number format to "text" won't convert any existing numbers in the column to text. You need to select the column and do a Data, Text to Columns operation, selecting Text format on the last screen.

Comment: I do not get you when you say "last screen".. Should I change the data type of the pivot table source to text in Format cells?

Comment: Select the column. Click Data, Text to columns. Select Delimited and click Next. Click Next again. Select Text and click Finish. Then refresh the pivot table and try running your code again.